# Assigning mouse keys to keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to assign mouse keys (left click 1, middle click 2, right click 3, etc) to keyboard keys by modifying a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had thought someone told me or I heard somewhere that xorg by default supports keyboard driven mouse emulation out of the box. The movement, etc. is bound to the numpad keys. This article I dug up quick seems to indicate I have heard correctly. No direct experience, so this may be incorrect.

See http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_use_the_numeric_keyboard_keys_as_mouse_in_XOrg

Comment: For completeness that's shift+num lock to toggle keypad-as-mouse mode. Works in Debian for me.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully thanks for the great input.